# Angular Meteor Socially Tutorial - Getting a blank page when trying to add Maps

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I am just starting off with Angular Meteor NodeJS, I am quite new to these topics.
The tutorial is awesome! Things were going smooth until I updated the code to have maps related code (step 16 in the tutorial http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/google-maps), the application stopped working and I just see a blank screen at http://localhost:3000

I see the below message on the command line (Windows) when the application is starting:

```
client/imports/party-details/party-details.ts (10, 9): Module '"node_modules/angular2-google-maps/core/index"' has no exported member 'ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_DIRECTIVES'.

client/app.ts (9, 9): Module '"node_modules/angular2-google-maps/core/index"' has no exported member 'ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS'.
```

Goggled the error, but couldn't gather more details on how to resolve this issue.
Is this something to do with version conflict? I am running on Windows 10.

My package.json has

```
 {
  "name": "socially",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.12.0",
    "angular2-meteor": "^0.5.5",
    "angular2-meteor-accounts-ui": "^0.4.3",
    "angular2-meteor-auto-bootstrap": "^0.5.5",
    "angular2-pagination": "^0.2.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into the same issue...

Found this: https://angular-maps.com/docs/changelog.html

ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS is now called GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS.
ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_DIRECTIVES is now called GOOGLE_MAPS_DIRECTIVES.

in case you haven't resolved it yet.